# How many people needed for a party?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

A party must contain 5 different people with the same date of birth in 2010.

How many people must be invited to satisfy the above condition?

Is there a specific way to solve this question? I'm really lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  The year 2010 was not a leap year.  That means it had $365$ days.  The worst case scenario is having four people with each possible date of birth.  If one more person attends, what happens?

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I'm really lost in solving this

Comment: If you have exactly four people with each possible birth date, then the party has $4 \cdot 365 = 1460$ people.  However, no day has five people with the same date of birth.  If you now add one more person born in 2010, then you are guaranteed to have five people with the same date of birth.

Comment: Thank you sir, Now I get it :)